# chained select with servlets,jquery,ajax, json

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Could someone assist here. I have the below servlet class and each time i try to select from parent category nothing gets displayed in subcategory. Have a look at the below if am doing something wrong .

Thanks

ajax part:

```
    $('#parentCategorySelector').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).prop('value');
            if (selectedValue == '--Select a parent category--') {
                $('#categorySelector').empty();
            } else {
                $.post('${PREFIX}/category', selectedValue, function(data) {
                    var categorySelectorList = data.categorySelectorList;
                    $('#categorySelector').empty();
                    $.each(categorySelectorList, function(key, value) {
                        $('#categorySelector').append($('<option/>', {
                            value : value,
                            text : value
                        }));
                    });
                }, 'json');
            }
        });
```

servlet class :

```
  public class CategoryServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * serialization
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2461387206258395143L;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(CategoryServlet.class);

private Connection connection = null;
int cat = 0;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("pages/all.jsp");
    dispatcher.include(request, response);

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    String parentCategory = request.getParameter("parentCategory");

    if (StringUtils.paramSet(id)) {

        request.setAttribute("CATEGORY", CategoryService.getCategoryById(
                Long.valueOf(id), connection));

    } else if (StringUtils.paramSet(parentCategory)) {

        request.setAttribute(
                "CATEGORY",
                CategoryService.getParentCategory(
                        Integer.valueOf(parentCategory), connection));

    } else if (StringUtils.paramSet(category)) {
        String categories = request.getParameter("category");
        if (StringUtils.paramSet(categories)) {
            request.setAttribute("CATEGORY",
                    CategoryService.listAllCategory(cat, connection));
        }
        dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/pages/all.jsp");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("CATEGORY",
                CategoryService.listAllCategory(cat, connection));

    }
    dispatcher.include(request, response);

    DBConnection.closeConnection(connection);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    LOGGER.info("TESTING " + action);

    if (StringUtils.paramSet(action)) {
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        Map<String, Object> resp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // resp.put("error", "Please fill in all fields");
         List<Category> categorySelectorList =
         CategoryService.listAllCategory(cat,connection);

         LOGGER.info("TESTING " + categorySelectorList);
        // resp.put("categorySelectorList", categorySelectorList);

        // LOGGER.info("TESTING 2 " + categorySelectorList);

        try {
            ResponseUtils.writeJson(resp, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter()
                    .write("{\"error\" : \"An error occured please try again. If the error persists, please refresh your browser \"}");
        }
        DBConnection.closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

}

and in jsp looks this way:

```
    <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError">Select
                                Category</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="parentCategorySelector" name="parentCategorySelector"
                                    data-rel="chosen">
                                    <c:forEach items="${PARENTCATEGORY}" var="parentcategory">
                                        <option value="${parentcategory.name}">
                                            <c:out value="${parentcategory.name}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:forEach>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError">Select
                                type</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="categorySelector" name="categorySelector"
                                    data-rel="chosen">
                                    <c:forEach items="${CATEGORY}" var="subcategory">
                                        <option value="${subcategory.category}">
                                            <c:out value="${subcategory.category}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:forEach>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Try to separate and localize the problem. Does server returns something? Is this server side or client side problem?

Comment: Hi StanislavL,on the client side nothing gets diaplayed i.e data is null from below line..
var categorySelectorList = data.categorySelectorList;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ajax part i changed it to below

```
      $('#parentCategorySelector').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = this.value;
             if (selectedValue == '--Select a parent category--') {
                $('#categorySelector').empty();
            } else {
                $.post('${PREFIX}/category', {parentCategory:selectedValue}, function(data) {
                    $('#categorySelector').empty();
                    $.each(data.categorySelectorList, function(key, value) {
                        $('#categorySelector').append($('<option/>', {
                            value : value['id'],
                            text : value['category']
                        }));
                    });

                }, 'json');
            }

        });
```

servlet class :

```
public class CategoryServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * serialization
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2461387206258395143L;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(CategoryServlet.class);

private Connection connection = null;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("jsp/pages/create.jsp");
    dispatcher.include(request, response);

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    String parentCategory = request.getParameter("parentCategory");

    if (StringUtils.paramSet(id)) {

        request.setAttribute("CATEGORY", CategoryService.getCategoryById(
                Long.valueOf(id), connection));

    } else if (StringUtils.paramSet(parentCategory)) {

        request.setAttribute(
                "CATEGORY",
                CategoryService.getParentCategory(
                        Integer.valueOf(parentCategory), connection));

    } else if (StringUtils.paramSet(category)) {
        String categories = request.getParameter("category");
        if (StringUtils.paramSet(categories)) {
            request.setAttribute(
                    "CATEGORY",
                    CategoryService.listAllCategory(
                            Integer.valueOf(parentCategory), connection));
        }
        dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/pages/create.jsp");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute(
                "CATEGORY",
                CategoryService.listAllCategory(
                        Integer.valueOf(parentCategory), connection));

    }
    dispatcher.include(request, response);

    DBConnection.closeConnection(connection);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    int parentCategory = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parentCategory"));

    LOGGER.info("parentCategory id : " + parentCategory);

        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

        Map<String, List<Category>> resp = new HashMap<String, List<Category>>();

        List<Category> categorySelectorList = CategoryService
                .listAllCategory(parentCategory,
                        connection);

        resp.put("categorySelectorList", categorySelectorList);

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String s = gson.toJson(resp);
            response.getWriter().write(s);

            LOGGER.info("TESTING mmmm : " + s);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            response.getWriter()
                    .write("{\"error\" : \"An error occured please try again. If the error persists, please refresh your browser \"}");
        }
        DBConnection.closeConnection(connection);
    }
```

}

and in jsp i modified as follows:

```
    <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError2">Select
                                Category</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="parentCategorySelector" name="parentCategorySelector"
                                    data-rel="chosen">
                                    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${PARENTCATEGORY}" var="parentcategory">
                                        <option value="${parentcategory.id}">
                                            <c:out value="${parentcategory.name}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:forEach>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="selectError2">Select
                                type</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="categorySelector" name="categorySelector"
                                    data-rel="chosen">                                      

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And the above is working ok.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

try changing this:

```
var selectedValue = $(this).prop('value');
```

to this:

```
var selectedValue = this.value;  //<---using navtive js code is better
```

and:

change this:

```
$.post('${PREFIX}/category', selectedValue, function(data) {
```

to this:

```
$.post('${PREFIX}/category', {parentCategory:selectedValue}, function(data) {
```

since you are using `'parentCategory'` in your request parameter then you have to pass it in your `$.post` function as suggested (*`{parentCategory:selectedValue}`*).

Comment: Thanks Jai, let me change as above and see if it works.

Comment: @pmaingi its just an suggestion you still need to look for parameters which you need at the serverside to get processed.

Comment: The solution: In the ajax part i modified it and the below is working ok